# Visual Studio with git in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

I need to be able to run swift on my windows laptop for a class and I chose to use WSL to do this, since it seems like the least amount of hassle.

The problem I'm having is that even though git is installed on Ubuntu, the git integration for VSC only works when it's in Windows. WSL with git does work for a friend of mine, so it's possible. Having to switch between Windows and Linux everytime I want to do something with git is very annoying and impractical

Comment: I have git installed and working fine for both my Windows and WSL instances.  Treat them as separate installations.  For instance, C:\Users\myUser\.ssh has my SSH keys ( and a putty flavored one ) where $HOME/.ssh has my linux ones.  I TRIED to share the key file but the linux side will refuse to play with the permissions passed through from WSL.

Comment: Also, be VERY careful.  By default, the stuff in the WSL instance is case sensitive.  In windows it is not.  CRAZY stuff can happen when hopping back and forth unless you account for this.